# Container with most water, with pre-computation of possible bounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

Here's my attempt at leetcode's [container with most water](https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/).

#### Problem:

> Given n non-negative integers a1, a2, ..., an , where each represents
> a point at coordinate (i, ai). n vertical lines are drawn such that
> the two endpoints of the line i is at (i, ai) and (i, 0). Find two
> lines, which, together with the x-axis forms a container, such that
> the container contains the most water.

#### Solution

Precompute increasing left bounds dictionary `{height:index}` and increasing right bounds dictionary `{height:index}`. Then iterate through both dictionaries simultaneously until they meet in the middle.

This solution is really fast (>98%) but I really dislike the way I iterate through the dict keys. I implicitly rely on Python 3 dictionaries preserving insertion order and making an iterable of dict.keys is weird.

Here's a previous review of the same problem more focused on performance. [How to speed up the code for LeetCode "Container with most water" task?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256326/how-to-speed-up-the-code-for-leetcode-container-with-most-water-task)

```py
def maxArea(self, height: List[int]) -> int:
    if not height or len(height) < 2:
        return 0

    max_h = 0
    max_h_left = {height[0]: 0}
    for i, h1 in enumerate(height):
        if h1 > max_h:
            max_h_left[h1] = i
            max_h = h1

    max_h2 = 0
    max_h_right = {height[-1]:len(height)-1} 
    for j in range(len(height)-1,-1, -1): # Is enumerate reversed cleaner ? 
        h2 = height[j]
        if h2 > max_h2:
            max_h_right[h2] = j
            max_h2 = h2
            if max_h2 == max_h:
                break

    left_bounds = (k for k in max_h_left)  # These feel wrong!
    right_bounds = (k for k in max_h_right)
    left = next(left_bounds)
    right = next(right_bounds)

    max_area = 0
    while True:
        try:
            max_area = max(
                max_area, min(left, right) * abs(max_h_left[left] - max_h_right[right])
            )
            if left > right:
                right = next(right_bounds)
            else:
                left = next(left_bounds)
        except StopIteration:
            return max_area
```

Two previous JS code reviews for reference:

- [Container with most water](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/container-with-most-water)
- [Leetcode container with most water](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232488/leetcode-container-with-most-water)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Iterating over height-index pairs

> I implicitly rely on Python 3 dictionaries preserving insertion order and making an iterable of dict.keys is weird.

This seems fine to me.
It's [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) that dictionaries preserve insertion order,
from version 3.7.
I would add a comment in the code as a reminder,
just to help readers who may not be too familiar with Python.

On the other hand,
since you only access the key-value pairs in insertion order,
you don't actually need a dictionary.
You just need a list of the key-value pairs, and iterate over that.

```
max_h_left = [(height[0], 0)]
for i, h1 in enumerate(height):
    if h1 > max_h:
        max_h_left.append((h1, i))
        max_h = h1

# ... similarly for max_h_right

left_it = iter(max_h_left)
left, left_index = next(left_it)

# ... and so on
```

#### Unnecessary `abs`

On this line:

> ```
> max_area, min(left, right) * abs(max_h_left[left] - max_h_right[right])
> ```

If you flip the left and right indexes, then you can drop the `abs` call:

```
max_area, min(left, right) * (max_h_right[right] - max_h_left[left])
```

By the algorithm,
the left and right indexes will never cross each other,
therefore the right index will always be higher than the left index.

#### No need for iterators

The purpose of the iterators in the posted code is to skip items (from left or from right) that are not in a strictly increasing sequence.
You can achieve this in a more straightforward way,
with less code,
that's slightly faster,
and I think also easier to read:

```
def maxArea(self, height: List[int]) -> int:
    left = 0
    right = len(height) - 1
    largest = 0
    
    while left < right:
        width = right - left
        
        if height[left] < height[right]:
            lower = base = height[left]
            left += 1
            while left < right and height[left] <= base:
                left += 1
        else:
            lower = base = height[right]
            right -= 1
            while left < right and height[right] <= base:
                right -= 1
                
        area = width * lower
        if largest < area:
            largest = area
            
    return largest
```

Answer (score 3):

Two minor things:

Your type hint for `height` doesn't need to be `List`; since your algorithm (correctly) does not mutate `height`, you can generalize this to `Sequence`.

`(k for k in max_h_left)` and similar can be simplified to `iter(max_h_left)`.